# Android How to Set Text in TextView from A Public Static Method?

Tags: java, android, methods, textview

I have this in onCreate :

```
final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
```

And I'm trying to set a text in a method that is in the same class :

```
public static void NextTxt(){
        text1.setText("");
}
```

But it doesn't recognize the "text1".

Comment: Why does `NextTxt` need to be static?

Comment: @Simon I need to use that method from another class

Comment: *If* (and only if) the class is instantiated in your Activity and you can *guarantee* that the class's lifetime is not greater than the Activity, then pass a reference to the TextView to the other class.  If you can't guarantee lifetime, then you risk a serious memory leak so come back and ask about callbacks.

Comment: @Simon Hmm thanks for the tip Simon. This method updates the TextView and I need the other class to trigger that method / TextView update? What would be a better way to do this other than this way then? Sorry I'm a recent begginer.

Comment: Have you tried runOnUiThread()?  You can use that to update any views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that static methods aren't associated with any particular object, but with the class as a whole. As such, they can only see static fields in your class. Your `text1` variable isn't even that, if what you say is true. Instead, it's a local variable that only exists for the length of the `onCreate()` method. If you know you'll only ever have one instance of your activity (and that's probably not an unreasonable assumption), what you could do is use

```
private static TextView text1;
```

at the top of your class (or, basically, anywhere outside of a method). The `final` modifier doesn't buy you anything. Your choice of whether to make it public or private, but I tend toward private by default (unless there's a reason for something else).

The alternative is to ask yourself why `NextTxt()` is static; if you make it a normal instance method, then you'd still need to declare `text1` in the class, but it wouldn't need to be static. But then you'd need an instance to call it on.

Comment: I need to use the NextTxt() method in another class and that's why I needed to make it static? I see everyone is skeptic about the static methods and variables, which is the right way if I need to use a method in another class?

Comment: Placing Android Context classes (EditText, TextView e.t.c) in static fields is a bad idea and is frowned upon cause they expose your application to memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView text1;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
}
```

Do the initialization  in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is static, you cannot access any of the non-static fields of the class. You have to make your textField static or pass it as a parameter.

```
static TextView text1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyClass.text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
}

public static void NextTxt(){
    MyClass.text1.setText("");
}
```

Of course you can only have one textField set at the time, because it's a static field of the class. The other options include making a singleton or removing static modifier from your NextTxt method.

Answer (score 1):

If it's true that this line is in your onCreate method

```
final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
```

then the answer to your question is that text1 is out of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) from within your NextTxt method. You've declared and initialized a variable within one method and you're trying to access it from another one. In order for the NextTxt method to "see" text1, you need to move that member to a place where both methods can access it.

As mentioned in other answers, you're also dealing with the fact that onCreate is an instance method while NextTxt is a static method. You may be tempted to start making everything static in order to "fix" your issues, but this is a dangerous and sloppy path. You don't have control over when Android kills your UI, so text1 could become invalid with no warning. The next time you try to call a method on it, you won't like the results.

Rethink what you're trying to do, sketching it out if necessary and don't just apply quick fixes in Eclipse if you don't understand the error.

Comment: I need to use the NextTxt() method in another class and that's why I needed to make it static. I see everyone is skeptic about the static methods and variables. So what is the right way of doing this if I need to use a method in another class?

Answer (score -2):

text1 is a `local` variable you have to declare it as an attribute of your class

```
public final TextView text1;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
}
```

and in your static method use:

```
public static void NextTxt(){
        text1.setText("");
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a final variable. It won't build